# Flutter "Null check operator used on a null value" when using GridView.Builder() inside of a StickerHeader widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, null

The idea is to have a sticky header to work with a `GridView`. I want the user to see a sticky header at the top of their screen when they are scrolling down the `GridView`.

Getting the "Null check operator used on a null value" error when the BlocBuilder creates the widgets when the if-clause statement `if (state.isAvatarFetchSuccess)` is equal to true. Basically `_stickyHeader.render()` just returns a `StickyHeader` from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers). The console outputs that the error specifically happens on the `return BlocBuilder<AvatarSettingsBloc, AvatarSettingsState>(` line.

I tried using `StickyHeader` directly as a widget, without using the abstract factory desing pattern, but it did not solve the problem. I debugged whether the data that is being used, the `List` that have the data to be generated into the necessary widgets by the `GridView`, but I can verify that the `List` is not empty. I tried using `ListView`, produced the same error. I googled the error message expecting to find a solution, but it seems like this is an "abstract" issue, and not something that happens in a combination of certain widgets, as far as I understand.

Does this have something to do with the new "Null Safety" update? Current Flutter version is 2.0.5. Here is a dump from `flutter doctor`.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AvatarSettingsBloc, AvatarSettingsState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
            if (state.isAvatarFetchSuccess) {
                print('avatar_settings_page avatarUrlList: ${state.avatarUrlList}');
                return _stickyHeader.render(
                    headerChild: Text('test'),
                    content: GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                        ),
                        itemCount: state.avatarUrlList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            if (index == state.currentSelectedAvatarIndex) {
                                return Center(
                                    child: InkWell(
                                        onTap: () => _onAvatarImageClicked(state.avatarUrlList[index], index),
                                        child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                border: Border.all(
                                                    color: Colors.red,
                                                    width: 4.0,
                                                ),  
                                            ),    
                                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                                radius: 60,
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                                backgroundImage:
                                                NetworkImage(state.avatarUrlList[index]),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                );
                            } else {
                                return Center(
                                    child: InkWell(
                                        onTap: () => _onAvatarImageClicked(state.avatarUrlList[index], index),
                                        child: CircleAvatar(
                                            radius: 60,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                             backgroundImage: NetworkImage(state.avatarUrlList[index]),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                );
                            }
                        },
                    ),
                );
            } else if (state.isAvatarFetchInProgress) {
                return LoadScreen();
            } else {
                return Text('Error');
            }
        },
    );
}
```